# Writing content into a file in Angular 8

Tags: angular, yaml

I have been trying to write data into a file in angular 8.
I have tried using js-yaml, write-file in my code. But these have fs as a dependency.

Does anyone have a solution for this ?

fs is not supported in Angular version 6+.

Comment: web browsers don't have access to file systems as this will be a big security problem. You can't upload edit a file directly

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-save-as-twjbek
Found this, may help

Comment: I eventually want to send this yaml to file to my server.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-save-as-twjbek updated the same, you will get file object, which can be sent to server

Comment: Yeah @Piyush.This worked, Thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Following JS code works

```
// Creating a file object with some content
var fileObj = new File(["My file content"], 'sample_file.txt', {type: contentType});
console.log(fileObj);

// Verifying the contents of the file
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = () => {
  console.log('reader', reader.result);      
}
reader.readAsText(fileObj);
```

The above will create a file object which can be sent to the server. If you need to download the generated file, follow here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-save-as